# ¿Cómo mostrar registros de 2 tablas relacionadas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un CRUD con múltiples archivos; creé 2 tablas: una es *actividad* donde van todos los datos y otra *imagen* donde van solo los archivos asociados a la actividad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es: pasa que si usuario quiere agregar 2 o más archivos a la actividad, al momento de mostrar los datos de la consulta, se van repetir igual número de archivos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ocupé esta consulta sencilla:

```sql
SELECT a.nombre, a.descripcion, a.objetivo, a.cursos, a.seccion, a.codigo, a.fecha, a.comuna, a.numero_estudiantes, a.socio , i.file
FROM actividad a
INNER JOIN imagen i ON i.id_actividad_imagen = a.id_actividad
```

Lo quiero mostrar es que en la columna *file* me aparezcan las 2 imágenes juntas: *223526_10200626375121015_1296632947_n.jpg*, *imagenes.png*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo con GROUP_CONCAT asi:

```
SELECT a.nombre, a.descripcion, a.objetivo, a.cursos, a.seccion, a.codigo, a.fecha,
       a.comuna, a.numero_estudiantes, a.socio , GROUP_CONCAT(i.file SEPARATOR ',')
FROM actividad a
INNER JOIN imagen i ON i.id_actividad_imagen = a.id_actividad
GROUP BY a.nombre, a.descripcion, a.objetivo, a.cursos, a.seccion, a.codigo, a.fecha, 
         a.comuna, a.numero_estudiantes, a.socio
```

Comment: excelente me sirvió mucho, gracias nuevamente